# Debugging tool to see which snippets were included in a JSF page

Tags: debugging, jsf

As my JSF project has grown, I have organized my files into snippets and templates. Also, some snippets have template snippets so that it can be reused further. However, this has made finding out which snippets are used to make up a single page a little difficult (and unlike Java code. Netbeans cannot jump from template to template like it does between Java methods with "Go to Source/Implementation" etc.).

Is there a debugging tool that can aid to see which snippets were used to form the current page? Ideally, what I am looking for is something similar to [Visual Event for jQuery](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event)

If no such tool exists, let me explain what I'm doing currently to see if it can be improved. First, I capture a debug query parameter so that I can turn on and off. Then, in each snippet, I have the following snippet:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{authController.debug}">
       <div style="background:red">
           From siteTemplate.xhtml
            </div>
</ui:fragment>
```

Obviously, this is far from ideal since I have to type the snippets filename in each snippet. It would be much better if I could do this:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{authController.debug}">
<div style="background:red">
       #{Current_File_Name}}
</div>
</ui:fragment>
```

PS: Django has a wonderful debug toolbar that shows the templates used, the SQL's issued to generate the current page. http://www.packtpub.com/article/django-debug-toolbar Is there anything similar? The best I have seen is FacesTrace, but development on that seems to have stalled.

Answer (score 2):

Three possibilities for you:
  1) Chrome has an excellent debugger/console and you should be able to trace by the ID easily (this is what I do for my templates/components).

2) You can look at the "log" in Primefaces if you're not running Richfaces or a heavy JQuery implementation. It does a really good job of showing the events as they progress so you have a good idea of what's going on.

3) Use Composite components instead of snippets--this is what I switched over to and since they are a "library" it is easier to manage and reuse. The stack trace usually shows very detailed errors.

In your example above instead of:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{authController.debug}">
<div style="background:red">
       #{Current_File_Name}}
</div>
</ui:fragment>
```

I would probably have a library of "mine:redDiv"

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.String"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>          
      <div style="background:red">
       #{cc.attrs.value}
      </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

I realize that you're not trying to create a red box, but this component could be used in the greater process as follows:

```
<html
...
  xmlns:mine="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mine"
>
...
<mine:redDiv value="Hello World"/>
...
</html>
```

This pattern completely eliminates the "Snippet" import method replacing it with reusable components. Transitioning my project to this pattern cut the code base by ~ 50% and maintaining it is a heck of a lot easier now. For reference its a medium project with a very "stateful" approach meaning SessionScope and ViewScope as the primary scope for the beans and it is basically a CRUD application.

Its hard to say what you're doing from the example, but my guess is you have a lot of files and it is getting confusing. Composite components basically provide a way to get around this problem making re-use easier.

In response to your comment about Netbeans and following code: if you're not tied to an IDE Eclipse Web Tools does have `ctrl-click` navigation from `html -> java` and `html -> html` which is pretty useful. Mainly it evaluates expression language and links but it is a time saver if you've got some spaghetti.